# Is soundness implies consistency in all logical systems?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I am a physics student and I don't have a formal education in set theory and logic but I am interested.

Is soundness equivalent to consistency in any logical system?
When a theory is sound and we have a model, I know that consistency is a consequence of soundness.
Is consistency implies existence of a model in all logical systems?(I know that the converse is true)
Is there a sound theory where the consistency is not a consequence of the soundness?

Comment: What is your definition of "sound" if it is not the same as "consistent" ?

Comment: @ soundness : $a \vdash b \implies a \vDash b$, but consistency is that the logical system does not lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Soundness of a theory (relative to a standard model) and soundness of the deductive system relative to a semantics are very different things. But if no contradiction is valid in the semantics and the deductive system is sound relative to that semantics, then the deductive system is consistent. And for that matter, if a theory is sound with respect to some standard model, then it is consistent. So under any reasonable interpretation of the title question I can think of, the answer is yes.

Comment: But then you ask if consistency implies the existence of a model as if “existence of a model” means “soundness”, but that’s not any definition soundness I’ve ever heard (it’s called satisfiability). But the answer is “sometimes”. The property of a logical system that consistency of a theory implies satisfiability is called “completeness” and many logical systems have this (e.g. propositional and first order logic), and many don’t (e.g. second order and most infinitary logics).

Comment: @Does any consistent theory has a model? in second order logic or other logical systems.

Comment: @Arian my last sentence there says “no”. One needs to specify the deductive system for second order logic, but for any choice that could reasonably be called a deductive system, the answer is no. If you google around you’ll find a lot of stuff about second order logic not having a completeness or compactness theorem.

Comment: @Arian For instance, the arithmetical system of the natural numbers can be characterized uniquely by a second order theory $T$. But by the incompleteness theorem, any deductive system we use here will have an undecidable statement $G$ that is true in the natural numbers. So $T+\lnot G$ is consistent but has no model.